# vscode julia language server raises error for v0.6.2 but not v1.6.0

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

There is a large julia (v0.6.2) project which I am trying to setup/debug in vscode. I suspect that there might be a possible bug in the vscode julia language support v1.5.8 and so I want to see if that is actually the case, and if yes, see whether there is a fix/workaround for it?

**vscode:**

```
Version: 1.63.2
Commit: 899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
Date: 2021-12-15T09:39:46.686Z
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.15.8-76051508-generic
```

**julia:**

```
Version 0.6.2 (2017-12-13 18:08 UTC)
Official http://julialang.org/ release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

**Issue:**

[image]

As can be seen in the image, the first comment (the bottom-right comment) mentions julia executable path as a possible source of issue. The second comment appeared when I clicked on the "julia env:[loading]" tab (in the bottom middle of the picture in blue) to see what it would run. I should mention that I have set up the julia.executablePath exactly the same as another julia project but with a different julia version (v1.6.0) and the julia extension works well for that project. To further test the issue, I executed the following:

```
$ ~/workspace$ /opt/julia-1.6.0-beta1/bin//julia --startup-file=no --history-file=no -e "using Pkg; println.(Pkg.depots())"
/home/rasul/.julia
/opt/julia-1.6.0-beta1/local/share/julia
/opt/julia-1.6.0-beta1/share/julia

$ ~/workspace$ /opt/julia-0.6.2/bin//julia --startup-file=no --history-file=no -e "using Pkg; println.(Pkg.depots())"
ERROR: ArgumentError: Module Pkg not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("Pkg")` to install the Pkg package.
Stacktrace:
[1] _require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:435
[2] require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:405
```

The `julia --startup-file=no --history-file=no -e "using Pkg; println.(Pkg.depots())"` is the same in both executions, but the second one raises an error. Does it imply that vscode is not properly distinguishing between the different julia versions? What can be done to make a work?

Comment: `Module Pkg not found in current path.` sounds like broken installation to me

Comment: Julia 0.6 is the stone age.. I would be very surprised if the Julia plugin for VS Code support it.

Comment: @Antonello It seems so. I just found [the julia-vscode changelog](https://www.julia-vscode.org/docs/stable/changelog/#[0.11.0]) which suggests that they added julia 1.0 support, and dropped julia 0.6 support at some point.

Comment: At the times of Julia 0.6 the recommended IDE was Atom